# $\int_{0}^{x^2 (1+x)} f(t) dt = x$

Tags: calculus, integration

According to the second fundamental theorem of Calculus, for this problem $F(x^2(1+x))-F(0)=x$ can be used.

But I can't find a function F that works for this problem. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)}f(t)\,dt=x$ cannot hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For instance, for $x=-1$ it yields $\int_{0}^{0}f(t)\,dt=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A simpler way to solve it:**

$$\int_{0}^{x^2 (1+x)} f(t) dt = x$$
$$w=x^2(1+x)$$
$$\frac{dw}{dx}=2x + 3x^2$$

By using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 1:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2 (1+x)} f(t) dt=\frac{d}{dx} x$$
$$\frac{d}{dw}\int_{0}^{w} f(t) dt *\frac{dw}{dx}$$
$$f(w)*(2x+3x^2)=1$$
$$f(w)=\frac{1}{2x+3x^2}$$
$$w=x^2(1+x)=2$$
This holds for:
$$x=1$$

So:
$$f(2)=\frac{1}{2(1)+3(1)^2}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You already have $$F(x^2(1+x))-F(0)=x.$$ Now, differentiate both sides to get $$x(3x+2)f(x^2(1+x))=1.$$
You can now solve for $f(x^2(1+x))$ explicitly, from which you can solve for $f(x)$, as long as you choose your domain wisely (since $x\mapsto x^2(1+x)$ is not a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to itself).

---

To do the last part, let's substitute $y=x^2(1+x)$, so that $x^3+x^2-y=0$. We want to solve this for $x$. This is quite troublesome to solve analytically (since it's a cubic), but can be done: let $x=1/a$ and multiply throughout by $a^3$ to get
$$1+a-ya^3=0.$$
The idea here is to use the triple angle identity for cosine, $\cos(3\theta)=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$. We substitute $a=k\cos\theta$ for some constant $k$ to get
$$yk^3\cos^3\theta-k\cos\theta+1=0.$$
We need the ratio of coefficients of $\cos^3\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ to be $4:-3$, so that $yk^2=4/3$, or $k=\sqrt{4/(3y)}$. So
$$\frac43\sqrt{\frac{4}{3y}}\cos^3\theta-\sqrt{\frac{4}{3y}}\cos\theta+1=0\iff\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3y}}\cos(3\theta)=-1.$$
Finally we can solve for $\cos(3\theta)$ in terms of $y$. Then, once we appropriately restrict the domain, we can find $\theta$ and hence $a$ and hence $x$ analytically. Once we have $x$ in terms of $y$, substituting back into
$$f(x^2(1+x))=\frac1{x(3x+2)}$$
will give us the answer, since the LHS will become $f(y)$ and the RHS will become something in terms of $y$. This provides an explicit formula for $f$.

Comment: I don't get what to do in your last sentence.

I get $f(x^2 (1+x))=1/(x(3x+2))$
But after that, I actually have no idea how to go on.

Comment: What you need now is you say $y=x^2(1+x)$ and solve for $x$. But if you plot that function, for certain $y$ you get one $x$, but at other point you might get three possible values. But, for example, if you choose $x\ge 0$ domain, then you have a unique solution. Take this $x(y)$ and plug it into $1/(3x^2+2x)$, to get $f(y)$

Comment: @MathematicalInductionisfun We actually need to solve a cubic equation. I've added something about how you can do this.

Comment: I don't think this calculation is part of Calculus 1...

Comment: @MathematicalInduction sadly, I think you're right. But I don't see how else it's possible to solve the question; maybe there's an easy solution I missed?